# How do I set all text boxes in a pptx slide template to word wrap (Asian typography issue)?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007, word-wrap

My problem is similar to the one described here:
[How to set a textbox to wrap a word to the next line in Microsoft PowerPoint 2016?](https://superuser.com/questions/1329272/how-to-set-a-textbox-to-wrap-a-word-to-the-next-line-in-microsoft-powerpoint-201)

The solution is available in the [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1329272/how-to-set-a-textbox-to-wrap-a-word-to-the-next-line-in-microsoft-powerpoint-201#comment1986792_1329283) to the accepted answer

My problem is specifically due to the original pptx file having been created in a Korean version of power point. I received a pptx file with a single slide, to use as template. The slide contained a text box. For any selected text box, I can go to Home -> paragraph -> Asian Typography -? uncheck "Allow Latin text to wrap in the middle of a word."

However, whenever I create a new slide, the properties of the text box carries over and I need to uncheck that option for the new text box in the new slide as well. Is there a way to uncheck this option for the slide template for this one particular pptx file?

Comment: Please try to right click the border of the text box that you have uncheck that option, then choose the **Set as Default text box**.

Comment: @Emily I don't have that option

Comment: See my reply to your comment on the accepted answer. With luck, it'll help.